# UIWebView setting custom width for the content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have the html content for my web view. When I load the content my web view makes the content scrollable in both directions, horizontal and vertical.

What I want is to limit content to width of the screen, so that each line of text just wraps onto next line on reaching screen width.

Currently my data loads the text correctly. It is scrollable vertically and text does not go out of the bounds and width.

But there are images in my content that goes out of the bounds in horizontal direction, and user need to scroll horizontal to see full image. I just want that if the image width is more than 320, then I could just resize into same aspect ratio to 320, so that my content is only verticality scrollable.

I have looked up on Stack Overflow and apparently these type of customizations can be done using JavaScript, but I don't know JavaScript.

Comment: Did you get answer to this question. I am facing the same situation. I know a bit of javascript. But, I do not have access to the webpage I need to display, so I can not use javascript.

Comment: solution was to format content from the web side only..didnt found for  webview